# Python: Generating a dictionary from lists

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops, dictionary

I am trying to have the `make_test(['Jon', 'Kate'], 4)` at the end below generate a dictionary where the name (Jon, Kate) is key and the each have a four lists (each with four integers), like `{'Jon': [[1,2,3,4], [4,3,7,-8], [-4,9,-3,-1], [-2,-9,-3,-1]], 'Kate': [[2,-1,-2,4], [-1,9,-8,-7],[1,2,5,-4], [-5,-4,-1,2]]}`. The lists with the four integers are made by `make_eq` (it generates n number of lists, in this case four). `make_eq` uses check to see if the three criterias set here are met. The code below just gives me an empty dictionary. Any ideas?

```
from random import randint
res = []
students = []
tests = {}

def check(ls):
    for n in ls:
        if n==0 or ls[0] == ls[2] or ls[1] == ls[3]:
            return False
    return True 

def make_eq(ls):   
    while len(res) < n:
        tmp = [randint(1,9),randint(1,9),randint(1,9),randint(1,9)]
        if check(tmp):
            res.append(tmp)
    return res

def make_test(students, n):    
    for student in students:
        for test in res:
            tests[student] = test
            res.remove(test)
    return tests

make_test(['Jon', 'Kate'], 4)
```

Comment: `for test in res` is an empty loop

Comment: Also, avoid modifying `res` while iterating over it

Answer (score 0):

```
# Importing
from random import randint

# Functions
def make_eq(n: int):
    """A function used to generate 'n' numbers of list containing each four random integers from 1 to 9"""
    lists: list = []

    for _ in range(n):
        lists.append([randint(1, 9) for _ in range(4)])
    return lists

def make_dictionnary(keys: list, n: int):
    """A function that generate a dicitonnary containing 'n' numbers of four-integers-long list for each keys in 'keys'"""
    students = {}
    for key in keys:
        students[key] = make_eq(n)
    return students

# Testings
print(make_dictionnary(["Student 1", "Student 2", "Student 3"], 5))
```

The "make_eq" function generates a list containing 'n' numbers of lists containing, again, each 4 random integers.

The "make_dictionnary" generates a dictionnary, that returns a list (see "make_eq" for more details) for each student :) !

Comment: Thanks @ColdFire! Is there any way to also implement the check function there?

Comment: @Amarillo Hey :) What do you want to check exactly in the list ? I quite dont understand the check function of your program... If you explain me, maybe I could help !